# PHP get ? without setting variable to anything

Tags: php, url, get

If I were to call:

www.*.com?hello

```
if($_GET["hello"]){
}
```

It will always return false because ?hello variable needs to be set as something...

Is there a way to get the ? part without setting the variable to anythign before hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if variable is set like this:

```
if(isset($_GET["hello"])){

}
```

sometimes `key_exists()` is better because if `$_GET["hello"] == null` you can get `false`

```
if (key_exists("hello", $_GET)) {

}
```

Comment: You are a hero.. I am a dumb ass.

Comment: @JamesT upvote on your comment for the self depricating humor.

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET["hello"]` is falsy, check if it's set at all

```
if (isset($_GET["hello"])) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
if (array_key_exists("hello", $_GET)) {
}
```

Please read this for a [difference between isset and array_key_exists](http://jontai.me/blog/2012/03/isset-vs-array_key_exists/).

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to check it like:

```
if(isset($_GET["hello"]) && $_GET["hello"] != ""){
  //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_GET["hello"]))
{

}
```

Instead of checking for both isset and $_GET != "".